# Add a carriage return after TYPE

Tags: batch-file

I created a batch file to merge some files

The files are generated automatically and named like this:

TimeEntries_2023-02-24 070714.txt

TimeEntries_2023-02-24 082025.txt

TimeEntries_2023-02-25 082025.txt
etc.

So my batch looks like this:

TYPE "C:\TimeEntries_2*" >> "C:\TimeEntries_Merged.txt"

But some textfile don't end with a carriage return and the last line of one file will by append with the first line of the next file.

How can I add a carriage return or a line feed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for %%q in (C:\TimeEntries_2*) do (type "%%q"&echo.)>>C:\TimeEntries_Merged.txt
```

should accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works for me, I just had to add the quotes in the route ("C:\TimeEntries_2*") and works so good, regards and have a nice day :)